# 16.04.6 - black screen on ubuntu desktop

Tags: 16.04, unity

After failed KDE installation I tried to go back to original Ubuntu desktop. Unfortunately after logging in, I'm getting the black screen, the x-style cursor is visible and operable and I can see only the Wi-Fi related pop-up.

When I go to the command line mode + startx - the desktop appears (looks like Gnome).

I tried to reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get purge unity
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

then reboot, the Ubuntu was not visible on the list on the login screen. Next:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

reboot, choosing the Ubutnu and I still have the black screen.
I tried:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

- it didn't work.

The Gnome and Gnome Classic is working but I want to set the default desktop.